Crystal Reports 2013 - Error: The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached
I am getting this error on the production server with my web application configured at IIS. Crystal Reports Runtime 64-bit is installed there. On restarting the IIS, reports are opening fine but after a certain period, the error "The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached." appears.

close/dispose/gc.collect at page_init event.
PrintJobsLimit increased from 75 to 1000 in Registry.


In your code, have you Dispose your report instance after showing it? It usually arises from this problem.

Contact your system administrator.

Assuming you are disposing objects properly, if you are using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio (rather than Crystal Reports Server), I believe there's a limit of 3 reports processing concurrently.
Consider implementing a job queuing mechanism to handle overflow cases.
